# Get Device Id Using Angular 10 Cordova

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, push-notification, native

I am Creating A Mobile application With Angular 10 + Cordova + Node. Here I have to send some push notification... I have done push notification with Ionic Angular && I have did in this project (web version) Thats working Perfectly with Firebase.. But no idea how to with native (Cordova) .

Asking help For:

1. How to retrieve device id for Push notification ? (I guess the Back End Part Will Be Same Just Have To Provide The Device Id For Mobile Device)

Here is The code in Backend (For Clearing Confusion)

```
exports.everyDayDueDate = () => {
  task
    .find()
    .populate([
      {
        path: "project_id",
        model: project,
        select: ["project_name"],
      },
    ])
    .sort({ status: 1 })
    .then((result) => {
      result.data.forEach((element) => {
        const a = new Date(new Date().toISOString());
        const b = new Date(element.taskCompletedate);
        if (b.getDate() - a.getDate() == 1) {
          User.findById(element.user_id).then((result) => {
            if (result) {
              let deviceId = result.deviceId;
              const payload = {
                notification: {
                  title: element.task_name,
                  body: "Working!",
                },
                to: deviceId,
              };
              const options = {
                method: "POST",
                uri: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",
                body: payload,
                json: true,
                headers: {
                  "Content-Type": "application/json",
                  Authorization:
                    "key=AAAAL0qgxio:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                },
              };
              request(options);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });
};
```

I just need to provide the device id to my backend, How Can I get That

*** Not Ionic ***

Comment: You gotta install the cordova device plugin, get the device id and then send it to the backend with some ajax

Answer (score 0):

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device`

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log(device.uuid);
}
```

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/index.html

Comment: I mentioned above Not In ionic

Comment: Updated my answer. Check if this works. Let me know if any other help you need.